Websockets on Cloud Run
I'm trying to set up a Cloud Run where I start a websocket (as a client using Node.js) to another server (that is providing the data I'm subscribing to) and sending that data to my database.
Basically like this:
Data source/websocket provider -> GCR (where I use websocket to subscribe to data source server) -> http call with data to put in database
I read through the GCR docs and all I keep in mind is that there is this 60 min timeout. Is that timeout for users that will connect to my Cloud Run (which there will be none, I just need one connection that will push all the messages received forward) or is it also for when I'm connected to another server?
Want to make sure how it actually works since it's not the standard practice Google docs refer to.

There are 2 side of your question.
Firstly, the request timeout is the ingress request timeout, I mean the request that invoke the Cloud Run service. If your Cloud Run instance open a connection on its own to an external server (egress traffic), there is no connection limit (imagine a database connection opened by Cloud Run service).
Secondly, I think you are using the wrong service for you use case. I understand that you need to listen an unbounded data source (like MQTT or Kafka or PubSub datasource) and when a message is delivered, you save it in a database.
To achieve it, you should use a batch service, like Cloud Batch (I think there is no real timeout limit, but plan a restart to refresh the VM), or Cloud Run Jobs (7 days timeout). Something new is also cooking on Cloud Run side, stay tuned

Thank you for the answer! So theoretically if I set up Cloud Run min instance to 1 (basically keeping it warm) then shouldn't it work out-of-the-box?
For Cloud Run Jobs I also found it's relatively expensive for a simple websocket service (just single connection to external source of data + http calls to db to save received data). Keen to share what's cooking on Cloud Run side? :)

I didn't catch you.  Cloud Run Jobs is at the same price as the always ON CPU feature (and less expensive as a request-based pricing). Can you detail how you figured out the cost of the service? (I fear a misunderstanding of Cloud Run service....

Sure, so I went here: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator -> Add estimate -> Cloud Run and then following config: region (us-central1), resource type (Job), CPU amount per instance (1), memory (0.1 GiB, not sure how much should I put), executions per month (20k), time per task (1 min). That would give $21.84/month.

Will your websocket only listen for 1 minute? And you run it every 2 minutes? You do not need a constant and stable connectivity? What's your question about the 60 minutes timeout? You lost me!

My bad, appologies! The 60 min timeout comes from this doc: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets#client-reconnects I need it to listen for new messages and they are quite frequent (usually 500/day) so yeah, I need constant and stable connectivity and trying to figure out if I pick the right tool for this or I should just get basic VPS and call it a day :D

If you pull a queue, normally, it's not mandatory to be always connected. The not pulled message would be kept on the producer side until your pull (or message timeout). If so, you can connect only a few time a day (in fact, it depends on your latency constraint) to save money. But, if you need a near realtime ingestion and/or the producer do not keep unpulled messages, you must run something 24/7, and it's more about $60 - $80 per month for 1 CPU.

Unfortunately, the produce side doesn't have any message timeouts nor will wait for me. Either I'm connected and get the data or miss out. So cheapest I could do it with Google products is around $60-80 per month? Just asking to make sure

It's a matter of tradeoff. $60-80 per month is for managed services like Cloud Run Jobs. But you can have cheaper, $20-40 with a simple VM. However, you will need to manage the VM (secure it, patch it, update it,..) and with serverless (Cloud Run) you have nothing to do.

Thank you! One more question: you mentioned something is cooking on Cloud Run side - when approximately could that new thing be expected? Just to gauge expectations :)

Don't know! Big announcement but unrelated to that. I would say in the next 3 months, maybe a Xmas gift, but Google never communicate in advance the release date.
